# How to get the smallest possible Float in Swift

Tags: swift, floating-point

I want to find, programmatically, and portably, the smallest Float possible.

By smallest I mean the smallest > 0 Float. Any way to achieve that ?

Comment: Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking up the documentation for `Float` I found: `Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

> The least positive number.
>
> This value compares less than or equal to all positive numbers, but
>    greater than zero. If the type supports subnormal values,
>    `leastNonzeroMagnitude` is smaller than `leastNormalMagnitude`;
>    otherwise they are equal.